Dill Error while upgrading Cloud Composer Version
We are facing an issue with one of the Airlfow DAGs while upgrading our Cloud Composer version (composer-2.6.6-airflow-2.7.3 | Python - 3.11.5)
Please note the DAG used to run successfully on the previous Airflow version
test_dag = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="download_data",
    python_callable=download_data_func,
    requirements=["google-cloud-storage",
                  "google-cloud-secret-manager",
                  "cryptography",
                  "dill==0.3.1.1"], 
    python_version='3.11.5',
    use_dill=True,
    system_site_packages=True,
    op_kwargs={
        "ds" : "{{ ds }}",
        "dag_run" : "{{dag_run.conf}}",
    },
)

Here's the error trace
[2024-04-09, 11:46:56 UTC] {process_utils.py:182} INFO - Executing cmd: /tmp/venvsxxidpy2/bin/python /tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.py /tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.in /tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.out /tmp/venvsxxidpy2/string_args.txt /tmp/venvsxxidpy2/termination.log
[2024-04-09, 11:46:56 UTC] {process_utils.py:186} INFO - Output:
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.py", line 17, in <module>
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     arg_dict = dill.load(file)
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -     obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO -           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:190} INFO - TypeError: code() argument 13 must be str, not int
[2024-04-09, 11:46:59 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1939} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 395, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 609, in execute_callable
    result = self._execute_python_callable_in_subprocess(python_path, tmp_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 446, in _execute_python_callable_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess(
  File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 171, in execute_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/opt/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 194, in execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/bin/python', '/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.py', '/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.in', '/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/script.out', '/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/string_args.txt', '/tmp/venvsxxidpy2/termination.log']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

We did try:

Playing around with different dill versions
Adding the package to the Airflow environment

The DAG used to run successfully on Python 3.8 and dill 0.2.7.1
Appreciate some guidance to fix the issue.
